# SSL certificate doesn't seem to be valid for 404 pages

Tags: c#, azure, ssl

My app is hosted on azure and written in c#. I am using the default free azure certificate.

The problem is, if you visit a page on the site that doesnt exist, the site becomes marked as insecure. this does not happen on other pages that exist on the site.

I have no clue how to resolve this. I want every page to be secured even if its invalid

Comment: Invalid==Insecure. The *browser* will always display sites with invalid certificates, or from domains that don't match the certificate, as insecure. The connection is encrypted using TLS, but the browser has no way to ensure it's to the correct server. What does the message say though? What is it that the browser doesn't like? Is the certificate expired? Or does the error page come from a different domain? `e-shop.com` is a different domain from `eshop.com`. So is `www.e-shop.com` and `errors.e-shop.com`.

Comment: TLS/SSL are used to ensure a connection isn't intercepted by something sitting between the browser and web server (a Man-In-The-Middle attack). This is done by encrypting the connection using the *server* certificate and verifying that certificate is for the actual domain the page came from. Without this, encryption means nothing - a malicious coffeeshop could put a proxy at `bad.coffeeshop.com` that *does* use TLS to fool the browser, read the data and then send it to the server.

Comment: If for "valid" pages the browser doesn't show a warning, the certificate per se is valid. Maybe there is some sort of redirection to a different domain (or even to `http://`) in case of an error?

Answer (score -1):

A SSL certificate is for a domain, not for a specific page inside a domain. If you get a warning about "insecure" for invalid (404) pages, then these pages are either served by plain HTTP (instead of HTTPS) or by HTTPS on a different domain with a broken setup. Which of these happens in your case and how to fix it is unknown, since the only details "C#" and "Azure" are not sufficient for debugging this issue.