# SSL Error on Azure App Service Default 404 Page for Invalid URLs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC application hosted on Azure App Service, and I've set up an Application Gateway with an SSL certificate. When a user tries to access an invalid URL, I currently don't handle the error, and the browser displays its default 404 page.

The problem is that this default 404 page shows an SSL error ('Your connection to the site is not secure'), even when the domain part of the URL is valid and only the last segment after the slash is misspelled. How can I address this issue?

Comment: do you mean, when we are test via a correct url, then there's no SSL error, and SSL error only occurred in 404 page? If so, do you define a  specific page for 404 error manually and does this page has a http url instead of https?

Comment: @TinyWang yes, particularly. I didn't wanted to have a custom 404 page for this application as I am not expecting user to modify the URL which we are forming specific to certain needs. So, when the URL is correct, SSL connection icon in chrome says "connection is secure" as soon as I browse non-existent url, I get  "Your connection to the site is not secure". & the url is still "https://"

Comment: Hi, `when the URL is correct, SSL connection icon in chrome says "connection is secure" as soon as I browse non-existent url, I get "Your connection to the site is not secure". & the url is still "https://" ` I'm afraid we shouldn't handle it like this. SSL security warning is not controlled by our code, but by the browser itself when we are using a unauthorized certificate like self-signed certificate. We control which certificate to use for our website and it's the browser to check whether it's security.

Comment: Therefore, if we implement your requirment, it would be redirect to another website page which website uses a self-signed certificate. Then we could see the browser that it doesn't show warning for insecurity unless user is seeing a website page using self-signed certificate. Pls correct me if I misunderstood  your idea.

Comment: @TinyWang yes, that was my understanding as well that it's browser to display ssl warning. my ssl is issued from valid CA. & it is registered for my domain, for eg: `https://example.com` when I browse `https://example.com/account/validurl` browser doesn't show any SSL error but when I add some random string at the end of url, like `https://example.com/account/validurl_random` I get 404 error & the icon near URL shows ssl error. This is my first app on azure app service so I thought I may have missed some configuration. All my on prem apps show no SSL error even when I get 404 error

Comment: I had a test in my side and I think I reproduced your issue, I checked on the internet and found some others also reported this issue. I also reached AI and got similar ideas.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4A5z.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue in my side, check the screenshot below. When facing 404 error, the browser showed insecure warning. If test with Edge, and clicking into the warning, it would indicate "doesn't have a certificate".

[image]

If we are facing the same issue, then it's not due to SSL certificate, but the browser itself. Or we can say it's recognized as the expected behavior. Here's a question which [had the same concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74898917/ssl-certificate-doesnt-seem-to-be-valid-for-404-pages) with you. And here's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48096#issuecomment-1536913310) reported before.

Generally speaking, 404 is also a kind of error which is considered as insecure so that the browser reported a warning, in Edge it also showed "no certificate". What we can do now is adding a handler for 404 error, such as set a custom page which displaying friendly message like "sorry the page is missing" in our application to avoid the real 404 error appearing in users' view.

[image]

Comment: That was great insight. I failed to search any existing threads with same issue. Thanks!